# How to render order completed page in ecommerce app in django

Tags: django, django-views

I am currently building an ecommerce style app. I have a view new_order that processes the POST data (order info). After that, it renders an HttpResponseRedirect to order_complete which just renders order_complete.html template.

What is the best way to pass the order number to the template. Here's what I did:

```
        messages.success(request, 'Your order number is %s ' % order.order_id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders:order_complete_url'))
```

That works nicely, however, due to the nature of messages, it disappears on page refresh. Is this an ideal behavior or there is a better way to accomplish it? Also, how would i go about passing for instance order detail, total etc, to the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's `messages framework` allow us to display a **one-time notification message** to the user after processing a form or some other types of user input. It temporarily stores messages in one request and retrieves them for display in a subsequent request (usually the next one).
So, when you refresh the page, that message will disappear and will not be displayed again.

You can use `session` to store variables which you want to use in your subsequent requests also.

For example:

```
request.session['order_number'] = order.order_id # set in session
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders:order_complete_url'))
```

This will set `order_number` in the session. Here, you can also set other variables which you need in `order_complete_url` view.

Then in your `order_complete_url` view, you can access `order_number` by:

```
order_number = request.session['order_number'] # retrieve order number from session
```

You can pass this `order_number` to `context` then for displaying in the template. Now, when you refresh the page, `order_number` will be displayed in the template.

Comment: Thanks! I will implement this now and get back to you